# Phorest REST API. CSV Export Job

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am currently developing a c# service that fetches data from Phorest API(https://developer.phorest.com/) and puts it in the database. 
I am new to REST and would like to know how to execute the POST method in the above link which creates a CSV as it has some sort of JSON body to be sent with it. I also tried accessing the CSVExportJob with Advanced REST Client but not sure if I am doing the right thing.

I am able to perform GET command as follows.

```
 public ObjectMapper PullDataFromPhorest()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization","Basic xxxxxx");
        string formattedContent = "";

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;  
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {


            string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            dataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectMapper>(content);
            for (int i = 0; i < dataObject._embedded.branches.Length; i++)
            {
                formattedContent += "Branch ID: " + dataObject._embedded.branches[i].branchId.ToString() + " Branch Name: " + dataObject._embedded.branches[i].name.ToString() + "\n\n\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
        return dataObject;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to post JSON data:

```
var url = "http://some-url.com";

var post_data = new
{
    field1 = "field1",
    field2 = "field2"
};

var client = new HttpClient();
var json = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(post_data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = client.PostAsync(url, json).Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // All good
}
```

This uses the Newtonsoft.Json library (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Since you correctly answered the question, I wondered if you knew what to do with the returned link. 
It looks like this. https://eu1-mem.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mem-prd/business/MVHUunOSK5fL_/csvexport/1weWb4RP-KSe?rX-Amz-Security-Token=. &X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20180110T111408Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=1799&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAJZQ6CH3SXRZO3WRA%2F20180110%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=8badf9b (Not the full link) But I am not sure what to do with it. When I put this in browser . Amazon AWS says NoSuchKey.

Comment: Hi Sabri. I don't know how to process that link unfortunately.